# How to store xml data type in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have some data with XML data type from a SQL server table, it does not seem that Bigquery has any equivalent of such, how do we store XML data type in Bigquery?

Anyone ever came across this scenario?

Comment: This previous question may help you with this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26127099/convert-xml-to-json-to-process-file-into-bigquery

Comment: Hi, thanks. But it is not a xml file I am trying to move, it is a sql server table with a xml column along with other columns.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update data in BigQuery, refer to [Data Manipulation Language](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/updating-data). Please take a look for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58801109/convert-xml-data-from-one-table-in-google-bigquery-to-json-data-in-another-colum) Stackoverflow question, which consider creating a new table from the existing one, then parses the `XML` column in Python to parse it to `JSON` format.

If your file is formatted as one record per line, you can load the data as a single column Bigquery table containing the raw string of each record per row first, then parse each `XML` string in each row with a [javascript UDF](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/user-defined-functions#javascript-udf-structure). Please, refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48954109/is-there-a-way-to-parse-xml-tags-in-bigquery-standard-sql/49119133#49119133).